# How to handle samples with many replicates for population estimation,when sample size is small?

Tags: sampling, small-sample, finite-population

I have a sample with very small sample size ($n<10$) and I would like to estimate the population mean. However, some of the samples are replicates (for instance, sampled at the same location).
According to a previous discussion:

[Sampling with or without replacement?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49480/sampling-with-or-without-replacement)

If my sample size $n$ is large, I could consider my case as sampling with replacement, which provides the same unbiased mean estimation but a larger variance estimation, as compared to sampling without replacement. However, in my case, the sample size is really small. Thus the estimated mean would be biased due to the replicates. Any suggestion about how to handle this case? Shall I exclude the replicates? Or is there any general rule about the proportion of replicates required to be a random sampling with replacement?

Thanks

Comment: Does every location have the same importance to you? I am wondering if a weighting scheme might be appropriate.