# Computing covariance matrix from the given variances?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, covariance, covariance-matrix

How can I obtain the covariance matrix when all the variances of the variables are known?

This is from the paper
http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/papers/CSD-04-1330.pdf

> $$V_1  \sim \mathcal{N}(0,290), V_2  \sim \mathcal{N}(0,300), V_3 = -0.3V_1 + 0.925V_2+ \epsilon, \epsilon  \sim \mathcal{N}(0,300)$$
>   with $V_1,V_2$ and $\epsilon$ independent. Afterward, 10 observed variales are generated as follows.
>   $$X_i = V_j + \epsilon_i^j, \epsilon_i^j\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$$
>   with $j=1$ for $i=1,\dots,4$, $j=2$ for $i=5,\dots,8$, and $j=3$ for $i=9,10$ and $\epsilon_i^j$ independent for $j=1,2,3, i=1,\dots,10$. We use the exact covariance matrix to compute principal components using the different approaches.

How can I get this exact covariance matrix?

Comment: Simply knowing the variances is insufficient to specify the covariance matrix. You need to stipulate the covariances for the data you want to generate.

Comment: @gung It seems to me that all the required information is already present in this question, at least if we assume the $\epsilon^j_i$ are independent of the $V_j$ and $\epsilon$.

Comment: +1. I removed your `sparse` and `pca` tags, because even though the paper is about sparse PCA, this example and your question have nothing to do with it. Covariance matrix of $X$ is $10\times 10$. What elements of this matrix do you know how to compute, and what elements not? E.g. variance of $X_1$ is $290+1$. And covariance between $X_1$ and $X_5$ is zero. Do you see this? How  many elements can you fill in?

Comment: It appears that the original paper has a typo when defining $\epsilon$; the correct form is $\epsilon \sim N(0,1)$ **not* $N(0,300)$. (See my answer below for details).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need the following properties to calculate the exact covariance matrix.

1. If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent normal random variables then their sum is also an normal random variable.
   $X_1 \sim N(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2), X_2 \sim N(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2)$ if $X_3 = X_1 + X_2$ then $X_3 \sim N( \mu_1+\mu_2, \sigma_1^2+ \sigma_2^2)$. This holds even more generally when  $X_3 = w_1X_1 + w_2X_2$ as $X_3 \sim N( w_1\mu_1 + w_2\mu_2,  w_1^2 \sigma_1^2 +   w_2^2 \sigma_2^2 )$.
2. If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent normal random variables, then their covariance is zero (The reverse is not true; see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12842/covariance-and-independence) for more details.).
3. The covariance of a normal random variable $X_1$ with itself is its own variance.
4. The covariance operator is linear, ie. the covariance $\text{Cov}(X_1, c_0 X_2) =  c_0 \text{Cov}(X_1,X_2)$ and more generally $\text{Cov}(X_1, c_0 X_2 +  c_1 X_3 ) =  c_0 \text{Cov}(X_1,X_2) +  c_1 \text{Cov}(X_1,X_3)$.

The first property allows you to calculate the diagonal elements. The diagonal elements are the variance of each respective $X_i$. So for example for $i = 9$ one would need the variance of $V_3$ plus one. The variance of $V_3$ is:
\begin{align}
w_1^2   \sigma_1^2 +& w_2^2  \sigma_2^2 +  \sigma_\epsilon^2 =  \\
(-0.3)^2   290 +& (0.925)^2   300 +  1  =  283.7875
\end{align}
Based on this the variance of $X_9$ (and $X_{10}$) should be $284.7875$. 
[*Notice that for $\sigma_\epsilon^2$ I assume a magnitude of 1 instead of 300. That is because in the paper by d’Aspremont et al. there is a typo. The [original paper](http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/spc_jcgs.pdf) by Zou et al. does not have this typo. This is easy to spot. If this was not the case the original estimate of the first two components account for 99%+ of the variation could not be true.*]

The second property allows you calculate the covariance between independent variables, eg. $X_1$ and $X_5$. $\text{Cov}(X_1,X_5) = 0$.

The third property allows you calculate the covariance of $X_9$ and $X_{10}$. Notice that it will not be zero; $X_9$ and $X_{10}$ are constructed using $V_3$ as a common building block and $\text{Var}(V_3) = 283.7875$. We need the covariance $\text{Cov}(V_3 + \epsilon_3^9,V_3 + \epsilon^{10}_3)$. As the covariances  $\text{Cov}( \epsilon^{9}_3, \epsilon^{10}_3) $, $\text{Cov}( V_3, \epsilon^{10}_3) $ and $\text{Cov}( \epsilon^{9}_3, V_3) $  equal to zero then you are left with $\text{Cov}(V_3, V_3)$ which as we mentioned equals to the variance of $V_3$, $\text{Var}(V_3) = 283.7875$.

Finally,the fourth property (*bilinearity*) is what allows you to get the covariance of $X_9$ and $X_1$ (or any other $i = 1, \dots, 8$)? One needs essentially the covariance $\text{Cov}(V_1 + \epsilon_1^1,V_3 + \epsilon^{9}_3)$ which equals $\text{Cov}(V_1 + \epsilon_1^1, -0.3 V_1 + 0.925 V_2 + \epsilon + \epsilon^{9}_3)$. Expanding this and taking into account that the covariances $\text{Cov}(V_1,V_2)$ $\text{Cov}(V_1, \epsilon)$, $\text{Cov}(V_1, \epsilon^{9}_3)$, $\text{Cov}(\epsilon_1^1,V_2)$ $\text{Cov}(\epsilon_1^1, \epsilon)$ and $\text{Cov}(\epsilon_1^1, \epsilon^{9}_3)$ are all equal to zero you are left out with  $\text{Cov}(V_1 + \epsilon_1^1,V_3 + \epsilon^{9}_3) =  \text{Cov}(V_1, -0.3 V_1) $ which based on the linearity property is just $-0.3\text{Var}(V_1) = -87$.

That's how you get the final exact covariance matrix: 
\begin{bmatrix}
    291 & 290 &  290 &  290 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -87 & -87 \\
    290 & 291 &  290 &  290 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -87 & -87 \\
    290 & 290 &  291 &  290 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -87 & -87 \\
    290 & 290 &  290 &  291 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -87 & -87 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0   & 301 & 300 & 300 & 300 & 277.5 & 277.5\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0   & 300 & 301 & 300 & 300 & 277.5 & 277.5\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0   & 300 & 300 & 301 & 300 & 277.5 & 277.5\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0   & 300 & 300 & 300 & 301 & 277.5 & 277.5\\
  -87 & -87 & -87 & -87 & 277.5 & 277.5& 277.5 & 277.5& 284.7875 & 283.7875 \\
  -87 & -87 & -87 & -87 & 277.5 & 277.5& 277.5 & 277.5& 283.7875 & 284.7875 \\
\end{bmatrix}

which according to MATLAB has the cumulative Fraction-of-Variance-Explained (FVE) from each principal mode of variation equal to: 
\begin{align}
  \lambda =  \begin{bmatrix}  0.6004\\
    0.9968\\
    0.9976\\
    0.9980\\
    0.9983\\
    0.9986\\
    0.9990\\
    0.9993\\
    0.9997\\
    1.0000\end{bmatrix}   
\end{align}

For the kicks I also do a simulation (in MATLAB) to make sure I get the very similar results with the paper:

```
rng(123)
N = 400^3;
V1 = random('normal', 0,sqrt(290), N, 1);                       
V2 = random('normal', 0,sqrt(300), N, 1);                 
V3 = -0.3*V1 + 0.925*V2 +  random('normal', 0,1, N,1);
X = [ V1+ randn(N,1), V1+ randn(N,1), V1+ randn(N,1), V1+ randn(N,1),...
      V2+ randn(N,1), V2+ randn(N,1), V2+ randn(N,1), V2+ randn(N,1),...
      V3+ randn(N,1), V3+ randn(N,1)];                             
[V,D] = eig(cov(X)); 
cumsum( flipud(diag(D))) ./ sum(diag(D))             
%ans =
%    0.6006
%    0.9968  << Yeap, it works.
%    0.9976
%    0.9980
%    0.9983
%    0.9986
%    0.9990
%    0.9993
%    0.9997
%    1.0000
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! Let me ask one more thing, why is "3.The covariance of a normal random variable X1 with itself is its own variance."? Is there any site I can see the proof of this?

Comment: That assertion is trivial: the two definitions agree, regardless of the underlying distribution of $X_1$.

Comment: @user26767: As whuber mentioned this is consider an elementary result. To quote Wikipedia: "[*Variance is a special case of the covariance when the two variables are identical*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Properties)". One can easily see this by taking the standard formula for the covariance of $X_1$ and $X_2$ $E[(X_1-E[X_1])(X_2-E[X_2])]$ and substituting $X_2$ with $X_1$. The formula for the variance for a single variable comes up, $E[(X_1-E[X_1])^2]$.