# Covariance Zero Equals Independent?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

We know that $cov(X,Y)=0$ does *not* warranty $X$ and $Y$ are independent.  But if they **are** independent, their covariance must be $0$.

My question is: what kind of distribution must $X$ and $Y$ be for there to be a proof that " $cov(X,Y)=0$ -> that $X$ and $Y$ are independent" ? (I mean how to prove "if  $cov(X,Y)=0$ so $X$ and $Y$ are independent?)

Comment: Look [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/12844/213806) for a primer with a specific example.  It is not an answer to this question but it is a nice answer to a similar question.

Comment: It's not the case in general; you can't prove it when it isn't the case. There are some specific cases (e.g. bivariate normal) where if you know you have that particular joint distribution then covariance 0 implies independence.

Comment: The second paragraph seems to contradict the first paragraph.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why zero correlation does not necessarily imply independence](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/179511/why-zero-correlation-does-not-necessarily-imply-independence)

Answer (score 1):

Early analysis of this question can be found in [Lancaster (1951)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1467-842X.1959.tb00274.x) and [Leipnik (1961)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2311154?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).  In the latter paper the author analyses the conditions required for uncorrelatedness to imply independence in a bivariate continuous distribution.  If you have access to scholarly journals (e.g., through a university) then I recommend starting with these papers.  I will also give a bit of insight for a special case.

---

It is worth noting that **independence** of $X$ and $Y$ is equivalent to the following moment condition:

$$\mathbb{E}(h(X) g(Y)) = \mathbb{E}(h(X)) \mathbb{E}(g(Y)) \quad \text{for all bounded measureable } g \text{ and } h. $$

If both random variables have bounded support then the [Stone-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) allows us to uniformly approximate the functions $g$ and $h$ with polynomials, which gives the equivalent condition:

$$\mathbb{E}(X^n Y^m) = \mathbb{E}(X^n) \mathbb{E}(Y^m) \quad \text{for all } n \in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } m \in \mathbb{N}. \quad \quad \quad$$

(The case $n=m=1$ implies zero correlation, and the other cases are conditions for higher-order moment separability.)  Thus, for the case of random variables with bounded support, correlation of zero, plus higher-order moment separability at all orders is equivalent to independence.